# Pentaho error (Insert / update ETL Out.0 - Incorrect integer value: 'N' for column 'test_column' at row 1)

Tags: pentaho, transformation, insert-update

I have a transformation that is flattening all data to one json data.
There is a another column in my table which is `test_column` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0'.
Under the insert / update step, its showing error of :

Insert / update ETL Out.0 - Incorrect integer value: 'N' for column 'test_column' at row 1)

Need help on this as it wont insert data to my table due to the error and so far I cant find any related issues on google.

Answer (score 0):

tinyint(1) can hold a 1-byte integer, and 'N' is not a valid integer value.
Check and replace the value you assign to test_column.

R

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution to my problem. I just need to use the Transform Columns step